# Is there a way to find out if JQuery .load() function failed?

Tags: jquery, overlay, modal-dialog

Is there a way to determine if the .load function in jquery loaded something? I'm trying to load a page into modal dialog. When validation fails, it loads nothing. I want to close the overlay in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is (from [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) :

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help! Will accept the answer in a few minutes.